# web scraping using ipython and lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to get the `menu items` from this website:

```
http://new.holachef.com/daily_menus?menu_date=2015-07-06
```

using the following code to target the  elements inside which the text exists:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

def get_page(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    dom = fromstring(html)
    dom.make_links_absolute(url)
    return dom

dom = get_page("http://new.holachef.com/daily_menus?menu_date=2015-07-06")
dom.cssselect("#store_item_64419 > ul > li.meal-discription.clearfix > div.col-xs-8 > h2 > a")
```

however i get an empty output:

```
In [9]: dom.cssselect("#store_item_64419 > ul > li.meal-discription.clearfix > div.col-xs-8 > h2 > a")
Out[9]: []
```

i want to get the text inside that `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is running into this modal asking the user to choose their location.

[image]